# Running SDL/OpenGLES application on a specific DISPLAY in XServer

Tags: raspberry-pi, sdl, opengl-es-2.0, x11, egl

I am trying to port an application to an embedded system that I am trying to design. The embedded system is Raspberry Pi Zero W - based, and uses a custom Yocto build.

The application to be ported is written with SDL / OpenGLES to my understanding. I have a hard time understanding how to make a connection similar to the following depiction:

```
SDL APP -----> XServer ($DISPLAY) -------> Framebuffer /dev/fb1 ($FRAMEBUFFER)
```

System has two displays: One HDMI on `/dev/fb0` and One TFT on `/dev/fb1`. I am trying to run the SDL application on TFT. The following are the steps I do:

**First**, start an XServer on `DISPLAY=:1` that is connected to `/dev/fb1`:

```
FRAMEBUFFER=/dev/fb1 xinit /etc/X11/Xsession -- /usr/bin/Xorg :1 -br -pn -nolisten tcp -dpi 100
```

The first step seems like it's working. I can see LXDE booting up on my TFT screen. Checking the display, I get the correct display resolution:

```
~/projects# DISPLAY=:1 xrandr -q
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 240, current 320 x 240, maximum 320 x 240
default connected 320x240+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   320x240        0.00*
```

**Second**, I would like to start SDL-written application using x11. I am thinking that should work in seeing the application on the TFT. In order to do so, I try:

```
SDL_VIDEODRIVER=x11 SDL_WINDOWID=1 DISPLAY=:1 ./SDL_App
```

No matter which display number I choose, it starts on my HDMI display and not on the TFT. So now I am thinking the person who wrote the application hardcoded somethings in the application code:

```
void init_ogl(void)
{
    int32_t success = 0;
    EGLBoolean result;
    EGLint num_config;

    static EGL_DISPMANX_WINDOW_T nativewindow;

    DISPMANX_ELEMENT_HANDLE_T dispman_element;
    DISPMANX_DISPLAY_HANDLE_T dispman_display;
    DISPMANX_UPDATE_HANDLE_T dispman_update;
    VC_DISPMANX_ALPHA_T alpha;
    VC_RECT_T dst_rect;
    VC_RECT_T src_rect;

    static const EGLint attribute_list[] =
    {
        EGL_RED_SIZE, 8,
        EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 8,
        EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 8,
        EGL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8,
        EGL_SURFACE_TYPE, EGL_WINDOW_BIT,
        EGL_NONE
    };

    EGLConfig config;

    // Get an EGL display connection
    display = eglGetDisplay(EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);
    assert(display!=EGL_NO_DISPLAY);

    // Initialize the EGL display connection
    result = eglInitialize(display, NULL, NULL);
    assert(EGL_FALSE != result);

    // Get an appropriate EGL frame buffer configuration
    result = eglChooseConfig(display, attribute_list, &config, 1, &num_config);
    assert(EGL_FALSE != result);

    // Create an EGL rendering context
    context = eglCreateContext(display, config, EGL_NO_CONTEXT, NULL);
    assert(context!=EGL_NO_CONTEXT);

    // Create an EGL window surface
    success = graphics_get_display_size( 0 /* LCD */  , &screen_width, &screen_height);
    printf ("Screen width= %d\n", screen_width);
    printf ("Screen height= %d\n", screen_height);
    assert( success >= 0 );

    int32_t zoom = screen_width / GAMEBOY_WIDTH;
    int32_t zoom2 = screen_height / GAMEBOY_HEIGHT;

    if (zoom2 < zoom)
        zoom = zoom2;

    int32_t display_width = GAMEBOY_WIDTH * zoom;
    int32_t display_height = GAMEBOY_HEIGHT * zoom;
    int32_t display_offset_x = (screen_width / 2) - (display_width / 2);
    int32_t display_offset_y = (screen_height / 2) - (display_height / 2);

    dst_rect.x = 0;
    dst_rect.y = 0;
    dst_rect.width = screen_width;
    dst_rect.height = screen_height;

    src_rect.x = 0;
    src_rect.y = 0;
    src_rect.width = screen_width << 16;
    src_rect.height = screen_height << 16;

    dispman_display = vc_dispmanx_display_open( 0 /* LCD */ );
    dispman_update = vc_dispmanx_update_start( 0 );

    alpha.flags = DISPMANX_FLAGS_ALPHA_FIXED_ALL_PIXELS;
    alpha.opacity = 255;
    alpha.mask = 0;

    dispman_element = vc_dispmanx_element_add ( dispman_update, dispman_display,
        0/*layer*/, &dst_rect, 0/*src*/,
        &src_rect, DISPMANX_PROTECTION_NONE, &alpha, 0/*clamp*/, DISPMANX_NO_ROTATE/*transform*/);

    nativewindow.element = dispman_element;
    nativewindow.width = screen_width;
    nativewindow.height = screen_height;
    vc_dispmanx_update_submit_sync( dispman_update );

    surface = eglCreateWindowSurface( display, config, &nativewindow, NULL );
    assert(surface != EGL_NO_SURFACE);

    // Connect the context to the surface
    result = eglMakeCurrent(display, surface, surface, context);
    assert(EGL_FALSE != result);

    eglSwapInterval(display, 1);

    glGenTextures(1, &theGBTexture);

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, theGBTexture);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 256, 256, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid*) NULL);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrthof(0.0f, screen_width, screen_height, 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glViewport(0.0f, 0.0f, screen_width, screen_height);

    quadVerts[0] = display_offset_x;
    quadVerts[1] = display_offset_y;
    quadVerts[2] = display_offset_x + display_width;
    quadVerts[3] = display_offset_y;
    quadVerts[4] = display_offset_x + display_width;
    quadVerts[5] = display_offset_y + display_height;
    quadVerts[6] = display_offset_x;
    quadVerts[7] = display_offset_y + display_height;

    glVertexPointer(2, GL_SHORT, 0, quadVerts);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, kQuadTex);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
}

void init_sdl(void)
{
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_GAMECONTROLLER) < 0)
    {
        Log("SDL Error Init: %s", SDL_GetError());
    }

    theWindow = SDL_CreateWindow("Gearboy", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    if (theWindow == NULL)
    {
        Log("SDL Error Video: %s", SDL_GetError());
    }
    ...

}
```

At first glance, I discovered two lines: `vc_dispmanx_display_open( 0 /* LCD */ );` and `graphics_get_display_size( 0 /* LCD */  , &screen_width, &screen_height);`. I tried changing the display parameter to `1`, thinking that it refers to `DISPLAY=:1`, but it did not do anything. I added logs for screen resolution, and I get 1920x1080, which is the resolution of the HDMI display. I think there must be something with the EGL portion of the code that I'm missing. What should I do right now? Is my logic fair enough or am I missing something?

Any requirements, please let me know. Any guidance regarding the issue is much appreciated.

**EDIT:** I saw that some people use the following, but raspberry pi zero can not find EGL/eglvivante.h for fb functions so I am unable to compile it:

```
int fbnum = 1; // fbnum is an integer for /dev/fb1 fbnum = 1
EGLNativeDisplayType native_display = fbGetDisplayByIndex(fbnum);
EGLNativeWindowType native_window = fbCreateWindow(native_display, 0, 0, 0, 0);
display = eglGetDisplay(native_display);
```

Comment: Quick look at raspberrypi userland code makes me thinking you should try `VC_DISPLAY` envvar. It is unclear for what purpose application uses SDL (probably not graphics related). You probably can drop most of that egl/vc stuff and replace it with proper SDL window (not 0 sized) and opengl context. It is also not clear from presented code if you even need X11 at all.

Comment: @keltar Hi, thanks for recommendation. Could you please have a look at https://github.com/drhelius/Gearboy/blob/master/platforms/raspberrypi/main.cpp for the full code.

Comment: @keltar Unfortunately, setting VC_DISPLAY var did not make a difference.

Comment: That is all too specific for RPI. Can you launch minimal application with SDL2 (fullscreen?) window on display you need? If so, it should be possible to remove all that vc* stuff.

Comment: Please check my edit @keltar